# To call jdbc connection from different class getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

Tags: java, oracle, selenium-webdriver, jdbc

I have a main method which is used to fetch the values from database and later I use those values for further input data operations.

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {                

// Object of Connection from the Database
    Connection conn = null;                                                             
    Statement stmt = null;                                              
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    String getDB_IP = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_IP");
    String getDB_SID = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_SID");
    String getDB_username = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_username");
    String getDB_password = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_password");
    String getDB_port = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_port");

   // Open a connection
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:****:@"+getDB_IP+":"+getDB_port+":"+getDB_SID,getDB_username , getDB_password);

    // Execute a query
    stmt = conn.createStatement();     

    resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select t.*,t.rowid from s_adinfo t where adcode like '123465'");


    while (resultSet .next()) { 

    String firstLoginTime = resultSet.getString("FirstLOGINTIME");

    System.out.println("firstLoginTime = "+firstLoginTime);
   }
}
```

Now, creating this database method in a separate Class assume like Class A and calling that method in another Class assume like Class B. At the time I get an error like unable to load the driver.

**Database method in another class**

```
  public static String sqlQueryUsdpDBLastLoginTime ( String KeyNameOfDatabaseResult) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {


    // Object of Connection from the Database
    Connection conn = null;

    // Object of Statement. It is used to create a Statement to execute the query
    Statement stmt = null;   

    //Object of ResultSet => 'It maintains a cursor that points to the current row in the result set'
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        String getDB_IP = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_IP");
        String getDB_SID = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_SID");
        String getDB_username = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_username");
        String getDB_password = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_password");
        String getDB_port = Allocator.GetPropoertyfromfile("Database_port");

    // Open a connection
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:***:@"+getDB_IP+":"+getDB_port+":"+getDB_SID,getDB_username , getDB_password);

    // Execute a query
    stmt = conn.createStatement();     


    resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select t.*,t.rowid from t_adinfo t where adcode like '123465'");


    while (resultSet .next()) {                                                                                          
         keyNameValue = resultSet.getString(KeyNameOfDatabaseResult);                                                        

    }
    return keyNameValue;                                        
    }
}
```

**Console Error:**

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Jul 16, 2018 10:16:23 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at util.DBConnector.<init>(DBConnector.java:35)
at components.Corp.verifyLastLoginTime(Corp.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at components.LoadActionKeyword.<init>(LoadActionKeyword.java:104)
at components.Allocator.testcaserun(Allocator.java:116)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at
```

Comment: Add the class path and try to execute

Answer (score 0):

It look like you didn't add jar file of jdbc driver in the libraries folder

Download the ojdbc driver from oracle website and add to the lib folder inside the your project and create connection from the services tab

You can download from here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadojdbc14jar.htm

I am adding a youtube video link, just see their how to add jar of ojdbc driver and create a connection between java program and Oracle Database step by step(plese see the whole video) created by me

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmP-wOskDRc&t=187s

Expecting this will resolve your problem

Comment: Please don't link to obscure third-party websites, and if you do, don't link to ancient versions of the library (for Java 1.4). The latest version of the Oracle JDBC driver can be downloaded from Oracle directly.

Comment: if i execute this above given code inside public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException { } able to fetch the result successfully but when i created this database method is reused from other class with out this java main method facing this issue!